# game lagging after upgrading RAM

Tags: windows-10

I have recently upgraded my RAM from 4gb to 16gb ,there is no problem while working with the system even its faster but the games are lagging almost unplayable,i have Nvidia G_force 940M 2Gb graphic card Transcend RAM 16b DDR3 Intel i5 processor 5th generation .

Comment: What is the model of your motherboard? Did you check compatibility beforehand?

Comment: Yes my system was upgradable hoti 16gb of RAM and one time after upgrading it ran pretty  well but in the morning when I started playing games are lagging as hell ...but my sy is working pretty well even faster

Comment: OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393
System SKU M2W72PA#ACJ
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz, 2200 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date Insyde F.77, 18-12-2015
SMBIOS Version 2.8
Embedded Controller Version 89.50
BIOS Mode UEFI
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "10.0.14393.206"
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory 15.9 GB
Available Physical Memory 13.8 GB
Total Virtual Memory 19.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory 17.8 GB
Page File Space 4.00 GB

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I cannot see your motherboard in that list.

Comment: How can I view the mother board number without opening my laptop

Comment: Iam a little new to this

Comment: According to cpu z 
Motherboard 
Model 8096            89.32
Chipset intel biradwell-U  rev 09
Southbridge Intel biradwell-U -U PCHL-P rev 03

Answer (score 0):

Can you check  your previous memory frequency? (should be 1333mhz or 1600mhz or 1866mhz or 2133mhz) if your newer memory as lower frequency then newer one then you have your answer.

also you should check your memory cas latency (cl) the value should be sth between 7 and 16 if your newer memory has higher cas latency it is also answer to your question.

Comment: But if there was a problem with the latency and frequency then how the game ran perfectly for the first time after changing the RAM

Comment: You said that: "there is no problem while working with the system even its faster but the games are lagging almost unplayable" you did not say that for the first time they were running smoothly.

Comment: Yeah I missed that one

Comment: are you using old rams and new rams simultaneously  or are you using only new rams now?

Comment: also check if you are running dual channel and if your bios did not decide to downlock your ram for whatever reason

Comment: RAM 
TYPE DDR3 CHANNEL DUAL
NB FREQUENCY changing between 1500 to 2500 MHz 
DRAM FREQUENCY 800.1 MHz 
Latency 11.0 clocks delay 11 docks 
Precharge 11 clocks 
Cycle time 28 clocks 
Row fresh cycle time 208 clocks 
Command rate 1T

Comment: No previously was 4gb single channel now I have removed it with two 8gb rams

Comment: Iam running dual channel

Comment: So i think we should go back to  Ben Brookes question what motherboard do you have? or are using a laptop? if so what exact model are you using?

Comment: Iam using a laptop

Comment: According to cpu z 
Motherboard 
Model 8096            89.32
Chipset intel biradwell-U  rev 09
Southbridge Intel biradwell-U -U PCHL-P rev 03

Comment: if it is a laptop I would much appreciate its exact ,odel name. Because for me looking for laptop motherboard is a pain. It is much quicker with model name.

Comment: Notebook model - HP pavilion desktop
Product no. M2W72PA#ACJ
serial no. 5CD5194B6S
system board ct no. PFDXH018J8M0YR

Comment: Build id . 15WW2CIA601#SACJ#DACJ

Comment: according to this thread https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Ram-Upgrade-for-HP-Pavilion-15-ab029tx/m-p/5948054   you can use stick which are up to 1600mhx each if you have faster sticks you may have trouble. If yours are faster you should set their speed to 1600 in bios. I have to go for now so, this is my last post for now

Comment: Actually acc. To the thread his BIOS is not recognising the ram installed but in mine everything is being recognised ...I checked the bios also and ran a memory test no problems came ...is there a possibility that the graphic card  problem

Comment: You can try checking how much ram is shared with your graphic card yes and try to increase the amount. But dunnoif it helsp

Comment: How to check that

Comment: Okk I checked it with cpu z and dxdiag ..acc to that I have 2 graphic cards one is intel and the other is nvidia the total approx memory of intel is showing 8gb but showing not available in nvidia one

Comment: Yeah here it is ... 
Total avail memory 1201 MB
Dedicated video memory 2048 MB DDR3
Shared system memory 8153 MB 
System video memory 0 mb

Comment: Try to disable intel graphic card.  First ensure that nvidia is enabled

Comment: Dis that no success

Comment: did you try: From NVIDIA Control Panel:
3D Settings-> Manage 3D settings
The Tab "Preferred graphics processor " , select
High performance NVidia processor

Comment: I think the problem is not with the ram but with the graphic card or its driver

Comment: Yup I did the exact ..I even uninstalled the nvidia driver and downloaded it again ..tough the games performance is beter now but not like the first time I ran it ..means just after changing the ram

Comment: did you try the above? yes I think for some reason after changing ram your laptop decidet to switch to intel graphic card as default

Comment: Yeah ....the game is better now somewhat but like the time when I played it just after changing the ram

Comment: check how much ram is now assigned to nvidia ard and try if you can changeit in Nvidia controll panel

Comment: No i can't change that

Comment: Before the game ran with hiccups now no hiccups it's smooth but the gameplay is slow

Comment: didi you check if it is now using Nvidia? also try this http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/pc-components/how-set-default-graphics-card-3612668/